# Use of "not only... but also"

Tags: grammar, word-order, parallelism

I am an English teacher in Korea. Please help me to teach correct English to my students.

I found the following sentence in the book "Why We Shop: Emotional Rewards and Retail Strategies" written by Jim Pooler. I don't think it is grammatically or logically correct.

> At the office, it is important **not only** to look good and fit in; it's
>   **also** unusual for men and women to outdress their coworkers.

I think it is violating parallelism, not only A but also and it should be rephrased to the following:

> In the office, it is **not only** important to look good and fit in, **but 
>   also** unusual for men and women to outdress their co-workers.

Is the use of **not only... but also** correct in the second sentence compared with the first sentence?

Comment: Hi, Unison. Welcome to English Language and Usage. Your question reads more like a request for proof-reading and your sentences don't read well. Did you write it yourself? **Proofreading questions ("Is this correct?", "Are there any mistakes?")** or critique requests are off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified**. Please make sure that you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Yes, they are entences from "Why We Shop: Emotional Rewards and Retail Strategies" written by Jim Pooler. I am teaching the paragraph, but i think something is wrong with the paragraph.

Comment: I see. Asking one question per post is the guideline of Stack Exchange. I deleted your second question (which seems less important) and edited your first question focusing on **not only... but also** and please see if it is OK.

Answer (score 1):

I'd argue that the original sentence is valid.

> At the office, it is important not only to look good and fit in; it's
>   also unusual for men and women to outdress their coworkers.

In my opinion, the semicolon here makes the difference; there are now two separate clauses: one that says [paraphrasing] "looking good and fitting in is not the only important thing at the office" and another that says "it is unusual to attempt to outdress your coworkers". In essence, the sentence has used the words "not only" and "also" but is not necessarily a "not only... but also" construct.

I think your rephrasing is a little more confusing.

Perhaps a better way to phrase the sentence would be:

> At the office, it is important to look good and fit in; but
>   note that it is unusual for men and women to try to outdress their coworkers.